# タグwikiはどんな文体で書けばよいですか?

Tags: 討議, タグwiki

一般的に文章を書くときは文体を統一した方がよいとされますが、スタックオーバーフローのタグwikiではどの文体を標準としますか?

- ですます調
- だ・である調

Answer (score 2):

辞典で一般的に採用されている「だ・である調」がよいと思います。

といって、かちんこちんに統一すべきというわけではなく、文脈によって、「ですます」が自然な箇所では積極的に使ってよいと思います。(ある種のジョークなど)